# Is it possible to independently adjust the symbol size in the legend for tmap?

Tags: r, sf

When trying to plot a dotmap with tmap:

```
tm_shape(points)+
 tm_dots(col="Party")+
 tm_shape(districts)+
 tm_borders(alpha=0.5)+
 tm_legend()
```

I want the points to remain at their original scale, but want the symbols in the legend to be larger, as right now they are the same size of the individual dots and thus very hard to see. If possible, I'd like to have them in rectangles.

[image: Map with legend, legend points are too small]

This is how `summary()` on my dataset looks like:

```
   Party                    geometry    
 Length:61457       POINT        :61457  
 Class :character   epsg:3006    :    0  
 Mode  :character   +proj=utm ...:    0
```

Comment: What if you use `tm_legend(scale=2)`?

Comment: This changes the scale of the dots in the map as well.

Comment: And if you put `scale=1` in `tm_dots()` (and keep the `scale=2`)

Comment: The map always matches the larger number passed to scale, regardless of whether it is inside tm_dots or tm_legend.

Comment: I can't replicate this with sample data from the package, eg `tm_shape(metro) + tm_dots(col="pop1950")` using `metro` from `?tm_dots`. Dots on map and dots on legend are different and okay sizes. Can you edit and include an image? Or show summary of your data?

Comment: I edited the question with an image and a summary of the dataset. Doing the same as you did on the metro dataset gives me a similar legend as the one in the picture I included. I'm on tmap 2.2 and R 3.5.2.

Comment: I can also confirm that the problem persists after upgrading to tmap 2.3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By design, the symbols in the legend are as close to the symbols in the map as possible.

If you want the legend to be different, one approach is to create a manual legend:

```r
data(World)
tm_shape(World) +
    tm_fill("black") +
    tm_dots("footprint", size = .1, legend.show = FALSE) +
    tm_add_legend(type = "fill", 
                  col = c(tmaptools::get_brewer_pal("YlOrRd", 4, plot = FALSE), "grey75"),
                  labels = c("0 to 5", "5 to 10", "10 to 15", "15 to 20", "Missing"),
                  title = "Footpritn")
```

[image]